# React componentDidUpdate: check wether state OR props change caused the update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, memoization

I have a list-component with a lot of entries that come from the props which come from a Redux store. The entries are converted and filtered and put into the state in `componentDidUpdate`. But this function is also called, when the inner state of the component changes.

So I'm checking right now on every state change, if the entries from the props changed. That seems pretty unecessary to me because sometimes only one entry is different and the whole list needs to be compared to the previous one.

**How can I have something like a `componentDidUpdate` just for props?**

I thought about using [`getDerivedStateFromProps()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) but it says

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time.

Wouldn't this be good for my use case? I just don't see it as a rare one.

Then they [give advice to use memoization](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization) for this kind of problem. But then the memoization framework still has to check the props for differences as I understand it.

Comment: if you are shallow checking props changes, then go for React.PureComponent. React will handle props checking for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#shouldcomponentupdate) for comparing props

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases, you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or
>   state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called
>   for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

Answer (score 0):

shouldComponentUpdate() invokes once the mounting cycle completes not in first render 
componentWillMount() invoke before render.